# How I can capture both UART TXD and RXD signals?

Tags: uart, ftdi

I have the following setup (it's messy but I have no better skills to make it look better):

[image: original schematic that captures both incoming and outgoing traffic]

What I want to do is to pass through some sort of component both the TXD and the urd signals through the U1 TXD pin.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to capture both serial UART incoming *and* outgoing traffic into a read-only serial console whilst Arduino (or any other UART device) communicates as it should.

In other words: I am looking for what I can place into the "X" box in the following image:

[image]

What the X component must do:

1. traffic/signals from TX
2. traffic/signals from RX
3. Encapsulates it into some sort of data structure (eg. JSON) with some sort of timestamp
4. Send it back via USB to the U1.

The U2 would be the "normal" FTDI whilst the U1 would be the sniffing serial monitor.

As far as I know it can be some sort of microcontroller, but which one offers me a good read-only serial interface for my case?

Can you recommend what I can place into the "X" component?

Comment: +1 for schematic effort.

Comment: Anything with two UARTs so you can use the RXD of one to monitor RXD and the RXD of the other to monitor TXD. Then you put both lots of data out of one of the TXD lines to your FT232R. Unfortunately, specific product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: It looks like you have TxD connected to TxD and RxD to RxD, That would be incorrect.

Comment: Do you have a plan for how to handle the case where both TX & RX are active at the same time?

Comment: Turn on the UART's "echo" feature and the RXD data stream will appear on TXD.

Comment: be aware that some serial protocols are "chatty" (i.e. one side talks and the other side listens, then they change roles) and others are asynchronous (i.e. both sides talk at once). You need to think very well about the data structure that can reliably represent the asynchronous one.

Comment: @PStechPaul actually it depends on the specific chip

Comment: For just sniffing both sides of the communication to find out what's going on (as opposed to continuous monitoring) a cheap logic analyzer and Sigrok is very effective. But it sounds like you want more the serial equivalent of an Ethernet tap + Wireshark.

Comment: I was thinking more like the X to be some sort of microcontroller hooked to an Real time clock and both TDX and RDX to be hex-encoded and encapsulated as json with the timestamp from real time clock. A custom software will decode the Hex and use the timestamp too display the data correctly.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas [These](https://www.ti.com/tool/EZ430-F2013) are cheap and easy to wire up to perform the functions you need. You will have to write code, of course.

Comment: Consider running some software on your PC to snoop the communication. Do you really need another chip?

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/7K4a6Lh.png)  is an example of sniffing with a $10 logic analyzer:   Bottom is the query and top is the response (both with checksums).

Answer (score 1):

Connect the RX and TX to additional pins on the Uno and use a UART bit bang function to read the messages and then transmit to U1. Or have another device in the place of the Uno with two UART interfaces and connect TX and RX to it's RX1 and RX2 and send all received messages to TX1.